# Deleting lines 1 to 41000 at once from TextWrangler file

Tags: textwrangler, row-removal

I need to delete lines 1 through 41839 from a file using Textwrangler.  Is there an easy way to do this without having to manually go in an highlight all forty-one thousand lines.

Answer (score 0):

If your version of TextWrangler allows for it, search for

```
\A(.*\r){1,41839}
```

Otherwise, positioned at the start of the file, go for

```
^(.*\r){1,41839}
```

Replacing either one by nothing, should work, shouldn't it?

Or in a suitable shell

```
sed '1,41839d' t.txt
```